# Why does my Dell Inspiron 15 7000 Series (7537) show no display on startup?

Tags: laptop, bios, dell-inspiron

(Been having quite the number of problems with this laptop which is sad because it's honestly fantastic and I love it to bits, also hoping "questions" like this are okay on Superuser.)
I was recently having the issue of 5 beeps on startup from my Inspiron 15 7537, so I checked and this apparently meant a CMOS issue. Because of this, I opened up my laptop and replaced the CMOS battery, however, since then, the laptop will start up, but no video is shown on the screen. I can plug a HDMI in and get an output, however it's only a black screen which appears periodically then disappears, which makes me think it's for some reason in a boot loop?

I can manage to start the laptop while holding D to see the white-black-r-g-b screens, however when exiting or restarting, nothing else shows. I've tried restarting a bunch, holding power with battery and charger out to clear capacitors, replacing the CMOS again, testing both RAM sticks (and they both seem to work fine and nothing changes when I remove either), and nothing's working. I'd really appreciate some help! Feel free to comment/message me if you need any more info.

Cheers!

Luke.

Comment: What was the cmos error? Was it related to date/time? Or the cmos image itself?

Comment: Not sure, just checked the beep code and found "Real Time Clock (RTC) power fail, CMOS battery failure", not certain what the exact issue was.

Comment: Yep dead battery. Have you checked the Dell support for any bios updates?

Comment: Not sure how to install any BIOS updates as I'm getting no display, tried making a bootable USB and turning on with it in but nothing happened

Comment: Your still getting the backlight turning on right? Just not displaying the startup screen?

Comment: Yep, looks like the light is there but no Dell splash screen, windows screen, or anything

Comment: I think you are going to have to recovery the bios image. Do you have another windows computer you can extract files on? You are also going to need a USB, formatted to fat/16.

Comment: I do, I have tried that but I assume I did it wrongly - I formatted the USB and dragged the BIOS exe on, put it in the laptop and booted, but nothing happened, and as I have no screen output I couldn't force the laptop to boot from the USB, any suggestions?

Comment: You need to extract the exe, you will get two files from of it. One will be .hdr and one will be a .rom file. You then rename them taking off the letters and numbers. It will be something similar to 7537A01.rom you would take off the A01 in this example on both files. Then put both files on the fat/16 USB. Hold the end key when you start the laptop, you should see activity on the USB LED when it starts reading from it. You may have to try from different USB sockets. Some dells are picky about what usb you can recover from. Be patient in each attempt, it can take up to 5 min to flash

Comment: Trying to extract the exe, getting the message "Please install Intel ME driver before upgrade BIOS ...", even though I believe I already have Intel ME drivers installed?

Comment: Use Windows Command Prompt (run as administrator) to extract the required firmware files. Put the file in a easy folder like "c:\bios" then type these commands >
"C:\>cd bios"
"C:\bios>yourbiosA15.EXE /writehdrfile"
"C:\bios>yourbiosA15.EXE /writeromfile"

Comment: The two files you need to put on the USB renamed should now be in "c:\bios"

Comment: Ah, using the /writehdrfile and /writeromfile helped, thanks very much, I've now made the USB as far as I can tell and I started my laptop with it in and the end key pressed, I'll report back in a while or if there are any changes. Should I have seen anything on the screen? As far as I can tell the backlight is off right now, and shining a torch on the screen I can't see anything.

Comment: You should see activity on the USB, you may have to try different ports. All the dells I have done this to seem to want you to do it from a left side USB for some reason. It should reboot when it's finished writing the bios

Comment: The USB i used doesn't have an LED on unfortunately, I put it in a right side port as it's a lightning port, but I'll try it in a left side port.

Comment: The USB format is also important, I would try it with fat/16 first. Try fat/32 if it doesn't recover.

Comment: Trying with fat/16 right now (I believe, FAT in the Windows format menu is fat/16, correct? There's also FAT32 so I believe so), nothing seems to be happening right now, but we'll see, if it doesn't do anything in a few ports I'll try FAT32. Cheers!

Comment: I believe it is.. lol don't pin me down to that. Let me know how it works out for you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73675/discussion-between-luke-r-and-tim-stewart).